# Gauge linearity study: Definition

Tags: linear-model, gauge

In ISO 22514-7 "Statistical methods in process management -- Capability and performance -- Part 7: Capability of measurement processes" I don't understand how the **linearity** of the gauge is defined.

I understand how to check whether or not a gauge is linear. However, if the hypothesis test tells me that the gauge is non-linear, I should include this uncertainty in the *uncertainty of the measurement system*. In order to do so, I will need to estimate the linearity of the gauge, which is defined in Annex B.3 as:
\begin{align}
(i) \hspace{2em} y_{n\cdot} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_n y_{ij}\\
(ii) \hspace{2em} SS_E &= \sum_i \sum_j (y_{ij} - \hat{y}_n)^2\\
(iii) \hspace{2em} SS_{EVR} &= \sum_i \sum_j (y_{ij} - \hat{y}_{n\cdot})^2\\
(iv) \hspace{2em} u_{lin} &=\sqrt{\frac{SS_E - SS_{EVR}}{n-2}}
\end{align}
To me, these formulae have many problems. The best I can do is trying to fix them:

- Probably, formula $(i)$  should read $\bar{y}_{i\cdot} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_{ij}$, and similar in formula $(iii)$, $SS_{EVR} = \sum_i \sum_j (y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{i\cdot})^2$.
- Furthermore, I assume that in formula $(ii)$ we should use $\hat{y}_n=y_i^{(ref)}$ which is the **true value** of the $i^{th}$ reference.

However, if I "correct" the formula as described above, I do not obtain the results stated in the ISO norm examples. Does somebody know the correct formulae and a reference?