# linearity of a measurement device

Tags: measurement-error, linearity, gauge

I like to evaluate the linearity of a measurement system. In order to do so I read ISO 22514-7 as well as Breyfogle's "Implementing six sigma". However, the procedure is still unclear to me. So I'm going to describe the procedure, as far as I understand it.

Both references use the same data.

```
R-Code:
y    = c(2.7 , 2.5 , 2.4 , 2.5 , 2.7 , 2.3 , 2.5 , 2.5 , 2.4 , 2.4 , 2.6 , 2.4 , 5.1 , 3.9 , 4.2 , 5 , 3.8 , 3.9 , 3.9 , 3.9 , 3.9 , 4 , 4.1 , 3.8 , 5.8 , 5.7 , 5.9 , 5.9 , 6 , 6.1 , 6 , 6.1 , 6.4 , 6.3 , 6 , 6.1 , 7.6 , 7.7 , 7.8 , 7.7 , 7.8 , 7.8 , 7.8 , 7.7 , 7.8 , 7.5 , 7.6 , 7.7 , 9.1 , 9.3 , 9.5 , 9.3 , 9.4 , 9.5 , 9.5 , 9.5 , 9.6 , 9.2 , 9.3 , 9.4 )
yRef = c(2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10)
```

where $y=\{y_i\}$ is the raw measurement data and $\textrm{yRef}=\{\mu_i\}$ are the "true values". Now the data analysis goes as follows:

1. Plot the difference $y_i - \mu_i$ as a function of $\mu_i$. This yields the following plot:
   [image: linearityStudy]
   The black points are the individual differences $y_i - \mu_i$, and the red points are the average values. The $x$-axis displays the reference values $\mu_i$. The blue line is a linear regression curve, see next step.
2. Fit a linear regression curve to the difference of the average values (red dots in the upper graph). This yields 
   [image: linearRegressionOutcome]
3. Next, the ISO norm states that one has to use ANOVA to obtain the linearity. They state $linearity=0.58$, but their formulae are unclear, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442302/gauge-linearity-study-definition). In contrast, Breyfogle does not explain the evaluation at all. He states $linearity = 0.79$, which is approx. the $y$-intersect of the linear curve.

What I would do: The plot shows that there exists a bias of the gauge and that this bias is approx. linear. Thus, I would simply take the slope as linearity. The max. bias is then calculated as 
$$\textrm{max bias} = slopeFit * \frac{range}{2}$$ 
Is this, how linearity of a measurement system is defined and statistically estimated?

Answer (score 0):

The linearity is measured as
$$slope \times process\ variation$$

We obtain the process variation from a Gauge R&R analysis on this data. It would be the study variation portion.

More info here: http://www.statvision.com/Userfiles/file/PDFs/gage%20linearity%20and%20accuracy.pdf

Comment: I have to admit that your reference is exactly the kind of source I was looking at and which made me post this question. For the reference value "2" we have six measurements, but only three different value {2.4, 2.5, 2.7}. Nevertheless, the residual plot clearly displays four different values, which is impossible. Also, the coeffs of the fitted line does not match the dataset, but it represents those from my dataset.